# Fixed position with responsive nav and divs, why is it overlapping?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make this responsive with a fixed nav. How can I do that without the home column overlapping the navbar? I want the two columns to be flush together and resize with the screen. The nav needs to stay there as I'm adding several "pages" vertically down the one page. I feel like it should be obvious but I've been struggling for a while and I have read almost all of the recent answers and tried so many things and nothing is working for me.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #e5b032;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav a {
  color: #000;
  margin: 3rem 1rem;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #41dbb8;
}

.home {
  background-color: #fb7592;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Home</title>
<meta name="description" content="Home">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 </head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
            <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#bio">About the Developer</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </nav>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
        <div class="home col-md-9 d-flex">
                <h1>This is the content.</h1>
        
        </div>
   </div>
</div>


<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you do up a rough mock up of what you are looking for in paint and add it to your question?

Answer (score 1):

This will be the structure

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" style="width:200px">...</nav>
  </div>
<div class="home col-md-9 d-flex" style="overflow: auto;">
      <h1>This is the content.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

remove `position: fixed;` for `.nav` class

add `overflow: auto;` to `main content` to make scrollable.
also give some `width` to `left-nav`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #e5b032;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav a {
  color: #000;
  margin: 3rem 1rem;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #41dbb8;
}

.home {
  background-color: #fb7592;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#bio">About the Developer</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="home col-md-9 d-flex">
      <h1>This is the content.</h1>
      <h1>This is the content.</h1>
      <h1>This is the content.</h1>
      <h1>This is the content.</h1>
      <h1>This is the content.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This unfortunately didn't work. I got the same results.

Comment: Yes, I made the changes and then I was worried I missed something so I commented out my own css and copied exactly what you put. It's still overlapping and the home div won't stay flush with the side-nav.

Comment: add bootstrap script in the code snippet. make sure there is no `position: fixed`.

Comment: Okay I updated the HTML above to show the full html page. This is all I have so far as I literally just started this and got hung up on the layout.

Comment: I found, there are so many unwanted bootstrap classes. It gets harder to fix it with bootstrap. only suggestion is `row` and some other classes has `flex-wrap: wrap;` it is breaking the css. also in snippet, add cdn path of bootsrap script.

Answer (score 0):

Was it necessary? Left sidebar is now fixed with `position sticky` and `top 0`

```css
html,
body {
  /*height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;*/
  
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
}

.col-md-3.d-flex {
   background-color: #e5b032;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
   height: 100vh;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
}

/*.nav {
  background-color: #e5b032;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}*/

.nav a {
  color: #000;
  margin: 3rem 1rem;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #41dbb8;
}

.nav.nav-pills.flex-column {
  display: flex;
}

.home {
  background-color: #fb7592;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*position: relative;*/
  /*max-width: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  height: 150vh;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#bio">About the Developer</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="home col-md-9 d-flex">
      <h1>This is the content.</h1>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to answer. Unfortunately this didn't work. It made the viewport skewed with the 150vh and the sticky class doesn't make the side-nav stay put. There was also still some overlapping when I shrunk the page.

Comment: my solution works well, and I'll explain it .. 1. I set the height of the content to 150vh to show you how the sticky sidebar works; 2. Sidebar stickiness (yellow block) works well as the stickiness rules have been established; 3. The main content (pink block) is rubbery, and if you shrink the browser window, you will see that the text in the content block remains centered, which means that there is no crosshair. The task was completed according to your requirement in the description. Once again, carefully read my code, and carefully transfer my code to your project. And you will succeed :)